# “I'm writing my CV now.” versus “I write my CV.”

Tags: tense, time

I'm currently sitting at my desk and want to write on a social network that I'm writing my CV.

How must I write this message?

> I'm writing my CV now.

or

> I write my CV.

Comment: Note that "writing" only contains one "t".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**“I write my CV.”** is grammatical, but would not be used in this case.

In general, you'd be best off saying **“I'm writing my CV.”** or, because it's a bit different from activities one would generally class as “writing”, **“I'm *working on* my CV.”**

---

You don't need to write “now” at the end, because the timeframe is already covered by the contracted “am” in “I'm”, which specifies the present.

You might include “now” if you want to call special attention to the fact that you are engaged in the activity **right now**, such as in the following hypothetical conversations:

> “Have you made any progress applying for a job?”
>
> “I'm writing my CV now.”

> “Come with us to the park!”
>
> “I can't, I'm writing my CV now.”

---

There might be cases where “I write my CV.” is valid, but it generally sounds awkward on it's own. Here is a conversation and a story where you might use that specific form:

> “When you want a job, what's the first thing you do?”
>
> “I write my CV.”

> “So I get home, I write my CV, feed the dog and start to cook dinner. Guess what happens? The dog eats my CV while I'm busy chopping vegetables.”

The story in this second example employs the [historical present](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present), which is a complex (but common) thing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky area of the English language. In old English it was more acceptable to use the plain present tense to denote an action which is happening at the moment. It may also still be acceptable in British English:

> The master is not to be disturbed, for presently he writes a letter.

This usage of the present, however, is found in various forms in modern English everywhere. You can use it in relative clauses.

> As I write this letter, memories are coming to me ...

The main clauses uses the *be* + gerund construction for the present tense, but the dependent clause just uses the simple present.

> There goes the bus!

The present tense doesn't make it clear whether the action is happening now, or whether it is pervasively happening now, and in the time surrounding now. Compare:

> I go to school. [I am a student, enrolled in a school, where I have been going for the past two years, and will be for two more.]
>
> I am going to school. [I am on my way to school at the very moment.]

The second form is also sometimes used to express an ongoing activity, but it emphasizes the act.

Consider:

> He is writing a novel.

That doesn't necessarily mean he is doing it now, at the very moment. However, the meaning is different from:

> He writes novels. [He is a writer of novels, a novelist. Or, writing novels is something he does habitually, even if he is not mainly a novelist.]

We always use the plural, not "he writes a novel". What if we use a plural in the "be + gerund" form:

> He is writing novels.

This does not mean that he is writing two or three novels at the same time. The meaning now is very similar to "he writes novels", but subtly different. It means that "he is a writer of novels at the present stage in his life".  There is a suggestion that there is some limit: we remember a time when he didn't write novels, and maybe he will stop. But these days, he is writing them.

If a writer who has not been able to write for a while starts again, we would say:

> She is writing novels (again).

We would not say

> She writes novels.

because that just means "she is a writer of novels", which we already know, and moreover she is still writer of novels even if she is not able to write at the moment. If we use:

> She writes novels again.

It sounds archaic, like from the 18th or 19th century, or perhaps British English.

The sentence:

> I write.

means "I am a writer, in some unspecified form of writing".

> Q: What do you do?
>
> A: I write.
>
> Q: What do you write?
>
> A: I write a blog that nobody reads, and sleep on my parents' couch.

The simple statement that "At the moment, I am busy writing" is not expressed in modern (or at least North American modern) English as "I write" or "I write [object]". These are only ever used in dependent clauses:

> I am writing a letter to her now, and as **I write** it, **I ask** myself whether it might not be a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto TylerJamesYoung. I'd add that in English, we pretty much only use the simple present for on-going, continuous actions, not for actions that a person is specifically doing at that moment.

For example:

> What are you doing right now? I am writing a letter to my friend Sally.
>
> What do you do in your free time? I write letters to my friends.

Comment: What about this sentence: _What do I do now?_ I wonder why the present simple is used here.

Comment: When you have -- sorry, I'm not sure what the proper grammatical term is, but when you have these helping verbs that resemble a future tense like "should" and "do", then it is not a simple present, any more than "will write" is a simple present -- it's future. "I should exercise more." "I do like to eat chocolate." You can't say, "I should am exercising", that would make no sense. Anybody out there know the name for constructions like "should run"? Help!

Answer (score -1):

A straightforward answer to your question is: You say - "I'm writing my CV now". This is because you are updating your current status **before** starting it to write. This is exactly what do we say, *"I finished my work, I'm going to Church now."* This means you are *now* going to Church. While in the process of going, if you receive a call from someone asking your status, you may reply *"I'm going to Church"*